# Why is there a different button for 'minus' and 'negative' on a calculator?

Tags: arithmetic, math-software

Perhaps this is more of a programming question than anything else, and if so I'll gladly migrate it on over to StackOverflow, but I think this site might be a bit more suited. My question is: "why are there two different buttons for 'minus' and negative' on a calculator?". To my knowledge, they are treated the exact same way, the only different being that minus is binary, and negative is unary. Other than that, I don't see any difference. So why do calculators have two separate buttons for them? In programming languages, there is no distinction between the minus and negative signs, it is only calculators that make the distinction. Is it for the reason I stated, or is it something completely different? I don't see how the unary vs. binary would have anything to do with how a calculator computes something, but I can't think of any other reasons. Does anyone know why?

P.S. If it is for the reason I stated, could someone explain why that would affect how a computer calculates the value of an expression?

Comment: There's also two different buttons for 'divide' and 'reciprocral'.

Comment: I don't have a 'reciprocal' button on mine, but that's interesting too.

Comment: In calculators I'm familiar with, pressing [unary minus] multiplies the displayed number by $-1$, while pressing [binary minus] pushes a subtraction operator onto the evaluation stack, awaiting a second operand. That is, the distinction is between "$-x$" (a number) and "$x - $" (an incomplete expression).

Comment: But why even bother making them two separate buttons? In programming languages it's the same button, it's only calculators where it's different.

Comment: Suppose I have the number $42$ displayed on my calculator. I want to negate it and get $-42$, but my calculator does not have a "negative" button. I try pressing the "minus" button, but I don't get $-42$; instead my calculator sits there and waits for me to enter another number to subtract from $42$.

Comment: @Rahul: Based on your comment, I assume that you have an RPN calculator.  However, I've also seen distinct `-` and `⁻` buttons on infix-notation calculators like the TI-8x series, on which there's no obvious need to distinguish them.

Comment: @Dan: No, I have an infix-notation calculator. `42-` is incomplete input in infix notation; only once you enter, say, `42-3=` do you get a result `39`. How would you get from $42$ to $-42$ in your infix-notation calculator without a negation button?

Comment: @Dan: In a programming language, etc., one can easily use the single character "$-$" because the input system allows insertion in arbitrary locations. With a calculator, input can only be placed conveniently at the top of a stack. I believe this is Rahul's point, as well. If this reasoning is misguided, I'd be interested to know why.

Comment: That was exactly my point! Let me edit the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

The negative sign multiplies the number by -1. Minus subtracts the number, which is a completely different operation. The difference lies in where you can use it, as a minus sign cant be used on the first number you write, as there is nothing to subtract it from, and you cant use a negative between 2 numbers, as there is no operation happening between them.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  Although unary and binary minus are indeed distinct operations, a lot of programming languages, spreadsheet programs, etc., do manage to use the same symbol `-` for both of them.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple calculator that calculates an expression as you go along, there need to be two different buttons for "multiply by $-1$" and "subtract."

The "multiply by $-1$" button (often shown as "$+/-$") immediately changes the display to the additive inverse of the number: $9$ goes to $-9$ immediately after you push the button.

The "subtract" button (often shown as "$-$") needs more input afterwards, namely the amount you want to subtract.

On more sophisticated calculators where you can enter an entire expression at once, like:

`-0.85-(2/3.7)^2`

the extra button isn't really necessary, since you're entering the expression symbolically, and the calculator parses it symbolically as well.

Basically, the two buttons are the minimum necessary user interface for the particular chip set in the calculator.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same question, regarding an infix notation scientific calculator (where you enter the formula to calculate on a separate line, with ability to move the cursor and edit the formula at any point), e.g. a Casio FX series.
Casio has the (-) unary minus key, which I never use and think it would be better if it did a more useful and common function. In Casio FX, the regular (binary) minus can also be used for negation, as you would in a programming language. So in any particular formula, there's no difference at all between using − and - on a Casio FX. Expressions like −1−2, or 2^−2 give same result as if you would use the negation key for negation. The only difference I could find so far is - after you perform any calculation, and then press any of the 4 main arithmetic operator buttons (without clearing with "AC" first), the calculator will start the new formula with "Ans" followed by the operator. Ans refers to the result of the last calculation. If using the (-) key, the calculator will not insert "Ans" and will start a new formula from scratch (the - operator). I don't find it useful since I have a habit of always clearing the input using the AC button.